# Java - split string into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have this code

```
String speed_string = "baka baka saka laka";
String[] string_array = speed_string.split(" ");
System.out.println(string_array.length);
```

and it returns the value of 1 when I run it. Why is that? It seems as if only the first word of the string gets saved.

Comment: Gives `4` for me. Check if those are really spaces?

Comment: What you want to do actually?

Comment: How do I check if those are spaces? They're probably not as you all have pointed out. Writing \\s yields the same result.

Comment: above code give 4 for me as well

Comment: if you only want to check spaces `speed_string.contains(" ")`

Comment: I ran

System.out.println(speed_string.contains("\\s"));

and it returned false, both for "\\s" and " ".

Comment: I'm curious as to why this question gets downvoted? To me it's clear and straight to the point.

Comment: Try `for(int i = 0; i < speed_string.length(); i++) System.out.println((int)speed_string.charAt(i));` and check the output. Mine is "98 97 107 97 32 98 97 107 97 32 115 97 107 97 32 108 97 107 97"

Comment: It's because people downvote questions when they don't know the answer.

Comment: Huh. When I ran your code exception1, I got

97
115
108
100
107
106

Comment: @user1614466 Well, that's really strange, I don't know whats going on there... You could update your post, maybe someone else knows better.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\\s` and update the code as below

```
       String speed_string = "baka baka saka laka";
       String[] string_array = speed_string.split("\\s");
       System.out.println(string_array.length);
```

Comment: Thanks I tested this but it yields the same result. Is there a way to check what space is denoted with?

Comment: same result mean 4 0r 1 ?

Comment: The result I got was 1

Comment: ' Is there a way to check what space is denoted with' wht it mean ?

Comment: I meant that your solution is the most plausible, but since it still doesn't work there must be another symbol for space. Do you know of any else other than s? My mother language is Icelandic so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Can you run this byte[] byte_value = speed_string.getBytes();
     for (byte b : byte_value) {
   System.out.println(b);
  }   Have u found 32 value printed

Comment: Your code returned the following values:

115
108
100
107
106

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48408/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-user1614466)

Comment: @user1614466 did u send ?

Answer (score 6):

Most probably what you think is space (ASCII decimal 32) is not (in your input string).
That would explain perfectly the behavior you're seeing.